# Trying to open directly...Device open failed

Tags: miner-configuration, cgminer, ubuntu, phoenix

Ubuntu 13.10 & [amd-catalyst-13.4-linux-x86.x86_64.zip](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux%20x86_64)

xorg.conf created by

```
# aticonfig --initial -f --adapter=all
```

Thereafter, i modify it with next /etc/X11/xorg.conf

```
Section "Module"
        Disable        "dri"
        Disable        "dri2"
EndSection
```

Start phoenix:

```
$ ./phoenix.py bitcoin_deepbit_gpu.cfg
[10/28/2013 02:30:08] Welcome to Phoenix v2.0.0
[0 Khash/s] [0 Accepted] [0 Rejected] [DISCONNECTED]X server found. dri2 connection failed!
Trying to open directly...Device open failed
```

Start cgminer:

```
$ ./cgminer --scrypt  -T --url stratum+tcp://stratum.coinex.pw:9000 --user user --pass pass --no-submit-stale --queue 4 --scan-time 1
 [2013-10-28 02:41:21] Started cgminer 3.6.6                    
X server found. dri2 connection failed! 
Trying to open directly...Device open failed
```

I have partially solve this trouble with `--gpu-platform 0`:

```
$ ./cgminer --scrypt --gpu-platform 0 -T --url stratum+tcp://stratum.coinex.pw:9000 --user user --pass pass --no-submit-stale --queue 4 --scan-time 1
 [2013-10-28 02:43:12] Started cgminer 3.6.6                    
 [2013-10-28 02:43:12] Probing for an alive pool                    
 [2013-10-28 02:43:17] Pool 0 difficulty changed to 64                    
 [2013-10-28 02:43:17] Network diff set to 0                    
 [2013-10-28 02:43:17] Stratum from pool 0 detected new block                    
 [2013-10-28 02:43:19] Found block for pool 0!                    
 [2013-10-28 02:43:21] Found block for pool 0!                    
(5s):7.156K (avg):18.36Kh/s | A:0  R:0  HW:0  WU:35.4/m
....
```

But what is it?

**Trying to open directly...Device open failed**

Why does it trying to open device disabled by module directive in the xorg.conf?

And how to specify platform for phoenix miner?

There is only one option in phoenix config:

```
name = GPU 0 #The name to display the device as (default is device ID if not specified)
```

It doesn't help.

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly your question us?

Comment: Check, I'm trying to clarify it for you.

Comment: Do you have intel gpu?? try "sudo apt-get remove beignet"